# Closing a Windows Mobile Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, console-application

What is the best and cleanest way to close a console application on windows mobile?

The application by default is invisible and you cannot see it in the running programs, which is great for running a background process, but sometimes the user might need to close it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to to read a boolean (keep alive) in the config file and have another application set it to false when I want to exit.

Its not that responsive but at least I can exit cleanly..

Answer (score 1):

Exit Main.  Seriously.  If you need someone to be able to exit is manually, there needs to be some mechanism like a shell icon and menu or a program in the Programs folder of something.  How else would the user even know it's running?  Any one of those visual cues would then set a named system event, and inside your Console app you'd have something listening for the same event (likely a worker).  When it gets set, you take the actions required to shut down.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question.  I once spent a *long* time trying to figure this out.  Of course, we are assuming you can not (easily) return from Main.  The correct answer on the desktop is [System.Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx);  But that method is conveniently not supported on CF.

An apparent second option is [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx).  That is on CF, but only applies to WinForms, and is in fact not guaranteed to exit your application.

So, throw an unhandled exception. ;)

EDIT: To kill it programatically from another app, you can look at [Process.GetProcessById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k.aspx),  and [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx).  Both of these are available on CF.  You will have to somehow let the "killer" app figure out the "victim"'s ID.  More convenient methods like [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) are not available on CF.
  This technique isn't that elegant, though, and there may be permissions issues.

You could also consider some kind of IPC (inter-process communication), perhaps one overviewed in [this previous Windows Mobile answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200225/easy-ipc-on-windows-mobile#answer-200899).

Comment: that does not sound like a clean solution hehe. 

I was considering a 2nd application that terminates the first one. is something like that possible with console apps? since they seem to be invisible

Answer (score 0):

How would a user be able to close it if the application is not visible in the UI?

Comment: someone proposed that the main process checks periodically  a file to see if the flag to exit is set and terminates if it finds it. But Im searching for a better way of doing things.